# audioRecorderBeginInterruption not called

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

Just wondering if anyone else has come across this. The AVAudioRecorderDelegate methods that are related to phone interruptions are not being called. However, I know the delegate is set properly because it's audioRecorderDidFinishRecording method is called. I know I've probably done something to cause this glitch, because when I was messing around with it a couple of weeks ago, the interruption methods were actually being called.

Anyhow, does anyone have any insight as to why those methods wouldn't be called if the delegate is set properly?

NOTE: the issue is the same regardless of whether I use the AVAudioRecordedDelegate or add an observer for AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question lacks the code used for `AVAudioRecordedDelegate` and `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution to my problem. The issue is that I have an AVCaptureSession elsewhere in the app. In cases like this, it is important to let the capture session instance know that it is not to use the application's audio session. This is done simply like so:

```
    self.captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Now, your AVAudioRecorderDelegate will handle the interruptions (or, if you choose to use notifications, they will work as well).

Comment: how to declare self.captureSession (which class object) ?

Comment: That's implementation dependent. I have my own wrapper for AVCaptureSession.

Comment: i am use AVAudioRecorder what can i do ? if you know please tell me.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking me.

Comment: i have use AVAudioRecorder to record audio when call or play music i want to call audioRecorderBeginInterruption and after call ended or music pause i want to call audioRecorderEndInterruption but  audioRecorderEndInterruption are not call if you have any idea please tell me.

Answer (score -1):

Use notifications.
Here is a Swift example.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector:"sessionInterrupted:",
        name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification,
        object:myRecorder)
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the problem is precisely the same whether I use the delegate approach or the notification approach. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. FWIW, the delegate is deprecated in favor of the notification cha cha.

Comment: Sure - but where is that mentioned in the docs? There are a couple of end interruption methods that are clearly deprecated, but one that isn't.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/delegate

Comment: Ah, I missed the delegate. Thanks for that. So how do you know when the audio recorded has finished recording if you aren't supposed to use the delegate?

Comment: Oh, wait. That's a different delegate. I'm talking about the AVAudioRecorderDelegate, not the AVAudioSession delegate. The AVAudioRecorderDelegate has not been deprecated, as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorderDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Your object is wrong: it should be either `nil` or `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()`. You won't receive anything from your recorder.

Comment: @joelg `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`, `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` and `AVAudioSessionDelegate` are all deprecated, actually.

Comment: Downvoting 4 year old code because it is now deprecated is seriously uncool,  Cœur